# How to loop through JSON AJAX response?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I get an array from my ajax query

```
....
success:function(response){
 alert(response); 
}
....
```

I would like to create a jQuery loop which fires an `alert()` for each element of the array returned as JSON.

Comment: `for`, `.each`, `forEach` use any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a valid JSON you can use $.each()

> $.each() or jQuery.each() is used for iterating over javascript objects and arrays.
>
> Example : In the example below intArray is a JavaScript array. So to
>   loop thru the elements in the array we are using $.each() function.
>   Notice this function has 2 parameters

1. The JavaScript object or array that we want to iterate over
2. The callback function that will execute on each iteration

```js
$(document).ready(function () {            
  var  intArray = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500];            
  var  result =  '';           
  $.each(intArray,  function (index, element) {               
    result +=  'Index = '  + index +  ', Value = '  + element +  '<br/>';  
    alert(element); // alert the values 
  });           
  $('#resultDiv').html(result); //insert the concatinated values inside a div 

         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>             
  </head >
     <body>     
       <div  id = "resultDiv" >
       </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .each() method to loop array. Please refer to this for more info :- [JQuery .each() Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/).